# Update Statement with two tables -Oracle

Tags: oracle, dml

I have two tables and I need to Update the second table with a value from first table based on a common column.

I used the below statement

```
UPDATE emp
  2      SET ename = ( SELECT dname
  3                    FROM dept
  4                    WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno)
  5      WHERE EXISTS
  6        ( SELECT dname
  7                    FROM dept
  8                    WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno);
```

But am getting the error

```
ORA-01427 - Single row subquery returns more than one row.
```

Can you plese help me out?

Comment: why do you update ename with dname?

Comment: This should not happen unless you have two departments with the same number. Isn't deptno a primary key for dept?

Comment: This is just an example.The real query is 

update bons_nma_in a set a.bons_incident_number =(select b.incident_number from bons_outage b where a.NMA_TICKET_NUMBER = b.NMA_TICKET_NUMBER )
where exists(select b.incident_number from bons_outage b where a.NMA_TICKET_NUMBER = b.NMA_TICKET_NUMBER)

Comment: Then it's best you show us a sample of your two table schema please...

Comment: -1 for wasting everyone's time by showing a completely misleading query that does not have this problem. Please edit the question with your real query.

Comment: Iam trying to get a answer by showing sample tables.this is the exact replica of my original tables.I do not want to waste anyone's time

Comment: @user1969171: your example is not demonstrative of your problem. No-one can advise you on how to fix a problem you're not explaining correctly. Please update your question with a scenario that actually reproduces your issue.

Comment: DO YOU KNOW THAT GIVEN ABOVE SYNTAX IS CORRECT FOR THE TYPICAL EMP-DEPT SCHEMA IN ORACLE? Either you update your question with the correct table schema and sample data or stop wasting time. Don't know if others can, but I can't read your mind or seee your PC code *through* this question window!!!!

Comment: The question posed by Thilo applies equally well to your actual situation: is NMA_TICKET_NUMBER not the primary key on BONS_OUTAGE?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT dname
FROM dept
WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno
```

query must return single record.

check with

```sql
SELECT count(*), dname
FROM dept
group by dname
having count(*) > 1
order by 1 desc
```

or use

```sql
SELECT dname
FROM dept
WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno
and rownum = 1
```

Comment: Better not use the rownum trick. If there is really a department with too many names, an error is preferable to inconsistent data.

Comment: The issue is the query returns multiple rows and i need to update multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if 1st subquery returns only 1 value bcz if this subquery returns more then 1 row you want to update 1 field ename with 2 values from row and that's why i guess you have this error

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery to `dept` table is probably not returning one row. Add `min` or `max` operation to get one row from `dept` for each row from `emp`. Each setting value must be nonambigous.

```
UPDATE emp
    SET ename = ( SELECT min dname
                  FROM dept
                  WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno)
    WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT dname
                  FROM dept
                  WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno);
```

Remark1: in default SCOTT schema `deptno` is primary key, so no error would be encountered.
Remark2: shouldn't your question to be placed in [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)?

Comment: Yes it is returning multiple rows.is there any solution to update multiple rows?

Comment: If the query return multiple rows, what is Oracle supposed to do? Which of the department names do you want? You can set `ename` to only one of them.